# How to draw a rectangle with rounded corners using XML?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

Here is markup snippet for drawing rectangle with four rounded corners:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#fff"></solid>

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="5dp"></padding>

    <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

But if I want to round the corners on one side only (two corners), how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners 
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
    </shape>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
   <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a draw-able resource:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
 android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Set above in background of any view.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this with your requirement.

```
<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
```

or

```
<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
```

or any other this effect show you run time. May in xml file its show all corner round.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I suggest you to take the [tour] and read [answer]. Can you explain more why the code should fix the issue ?